# What topolects distingish between 娘 and 孃? Why?

Tags: topolect

In MSM 娘 and 孃 are usually considered one and the same, where 孃 is Traditional and 娘 is simplified. These two characters can practically be used interchangeably.  In [Southwestern Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwestern_Mandarin), however, a split has been maintained.

It should be a little something like this:

- 娘 = 阳平 = mom
- 嬢 = 阴平 = woman

I'm not sure if this a special feature of SWM or a remnant of something else. Do other topolects do this? Is there a reason for this split?

Comment: I'm not sure "why" can be answered. That's kind of like [asking "why" the word *blank* is differentiated from the word *bleach*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/b%CA%B0ley%C7%B5-).

Comment: I'm thinking that there might be some reason: like how 发 and 发 split to first tone and forth tone in MSM but didn't in other topolects.

Comment: You mean, to distinguish between 髮 and 發? Just like how SW Mandarin wants to distinguish between "mom" and "woman"?

Comment: Right. I'm assuming there may be a reason for it.

Comment: [This article](http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTOTAL-ENSE20050100F.htm) might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

孃 usually is used by people who live in southwest China, to refer women who are in the middle age. People in southwest China use it to call their older female relatives, or female strangers who seemed like in the middle age.

娘 means mom, but it usually used by people who live in North China. In South China, people call their mom as 妈妈

I'm a Chinese, and these are my experiences in using Chinese. Hope it helps.